# Install APK programmatically

Tags: android, installation, package, auto-update

I am trying to implement AUTOUPDATE functionality in my android app, as it is a custom app not published via android market. So far I have everything working, however android tries to install the App and says "APPLICATION NOT INSTALLED". I don't know if it is important, but the App is already on the device, so it is an update.

The app downloads the APK file from the internet and stores it on the SDcard. Than I do this:

```
    Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:my_package");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, packageURI);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + ApkName)), 
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The `Uri` you are creating in the first line and putting into the `Intent` in the second line is being overwritten by the `Uri` you supply in the third line. You can simply delete the first line and use the one-parameter `Intent` constructor that takes the action string. Also, don't use concatenation to create paths -- use the `File` constructor that takes a `File` and a `String` as parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a snippet I use, it looks basically the same as yours the only difference I can see is the use of packageURI. I don't know if using the packageURI would cause it not to work, but if I were you I'd try without.

```
File appFile = new File(ScreenSaverActivity.this.getFilesDir() + File.separator + APPLICATION_FILE_NAME);
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(appFile),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(installIntent);
```

However generally when you see the "Application Not Installed" message while attempting to install it means that the signature used to sign the 2 apk's was different i.e. one is release key signed, one is debug key signed. Or perhaps if the 2 apks were compiled on different computers you've got them signed with 2 different debug keys.

Note that even though you are not distributing via the market you still need to generate and sign your application. Debug key's expire after 1 year which your app will stop working once the key has expired.

Comment: Note that your code should only work if the file is `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`, since it is on your application-local spot on the internal storage (`getFilesDir()`).

Comment: Great point. I forgot to mention that, and it definitely gave me fits when I was implementing this.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you knew it. :-) But I wanted it on record for anyone else running across this answer.

Comment: You were right, the Signature was the problem. I didn't realize, that I was running the the app signed with a debug key and wanted to replace it with a one signed with normal key. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check whether the Application name specified in the manifest file is same as before.

2) I guess you may have to get some more package information to match. Especially if the application is built from different machine, the signature might differ (I am not 100% sure about this). 
Also if you are using Eclipse. Check under Run Configuration, check the package name specified whether it is the same as the one used for initial release.